# How much of MembershipProvider do I *have* to override in MVC3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Until now I have done all authentication work in my MVC3 app, i.e. validate a member, and create a member, through my `MemberRepository` class. I would now like to go official, with a custom `MembershipProvider`. So far I have only gleaned that I really need to override this class's `ValidateUser` method, and since I am not using a Login control, I'm not even sure I absolutely have to do this.

Overriding methods like `GetUser` and `CreateUser` brings uninvited types to my party, like `MembershipUser`, where I have a finely crafted `Member` class. Please can someone clear up for me whether or not I really need a custom membership provider, if I'm  not going to use any built-in controls or the admin tool, and if I do, should I confine my overrides to the absolutely necessary, which is what?

Comment: [Creating a Custom Membership Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/f1kyba5e.aspx)

Comment: Thanks @Robert, but that doesn't answer my question. I know how to create a custom Membership Provider, and am asking how far to I have to go in overriding the base methods, or can I e.g. leave them all at NotImplementedException, and if I can do that, do I really need a custom provider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Custom MembershipProvider**

It is possible to get some nice security features "for free" if you're using a MembershipProvider: You can set up web.config to redirect every non-authenticated user to a login page, for instance. Or you can set up specific parts of the site to only be visible to users with specific roles. If these features don't make sense for your project, or if you're already implementing their equivalent in another way, there's not much point implementing a custom MembershipProvider.

**SqlMembershipProvider**

One other possibility you may want to consider is actually switching your own implementation to use the SqlMembershipProvider to handle membership functions.

The SqlMembershipProvider provides a robust, proven platform for the common tasks that are annoying to have to reinvent for every project: account creation, validation, deletion, locking, password resets, basic roles, etc. If you've already done all of this yourself *without* using the SqlMembershipProvider, there really isn't any point creating one just for the sake of having it. However, you should be careful, because there's a good chance that you've done something wrong in your own implementation. For example,

- Are you storing passwords as plain text, or as hashes?
- Are you open to [Rainbow Table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) attacks, or are you salting your hashes?
- Do you lock people's accounts after you've seen 50 or so invalid password attempts in a row, or do you let hackers just keep pounding away until they've brute-forced their way into someone's account?

The SqlMembershipProvider has already addressed all these issues in an easily configurable manner. You may want to have your own membership interfaces and DTOs simply wrap this default MembershipProvider just so you don't have to worry about these various concerns. That way, most of your code doesn't have to interact with these "uninvited types," but you still get the advantages of a widely-used and proven security framework on the back end.

Comment: I think you summed it up nicely, thanks. I don't need a custom provider, nor the SqlProvider, but you have a good point with that provider for many cases.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one I wrote for unit testing. It's about as minimal as can be.

```
public class MockMembershipProvider : MembershipProvider
{
    public IList<MembershipUser> Users { get; private set; }

    private string _applicationName;
    public override string ApplicationName
    {
        get
        {
            return _applicationName;
        }
        set
        {
            _applicationName = value;
        }
    }

    public override bool ChangePassword(string username, string oldPassword, string newPassword)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool ChangePasswordQuestionAndAnswer(string username, string password, string newPasswordQuestion, string newPasswordAnswer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override MembershipUser CreateUser(
        string username, 
        string password, 
        string email, 
        string passwordQuestion, 
        string passwordAnswer, 
        bool isApproved, 
        object providerUserKey, 
        out MembershipCreateStatus status)
    {
        var user = new MembershipUser(ProviderName, username, username, email, passwordQuestion, null, isApproved, false, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now);
        Users.Add(user);
        status = MembershipCreateStatus.Success;
        return user;
    }

    public override bool DeleteUser(string username, bool deleteAllRelatedData)
    {
        var u = Users.Where(mu => mu.UserName.Equals(username, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).FirstOrDefault();
        if (u == null) return false;
        Users.Remove(u);
        return true;
    }

    public override bool EnablePasswordReset
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override bool EnablePasswordRetrieval
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override MembershipUserCollection FindUsersByEmail(string emailToMatch, int pageIndex, int pageSize, out int totalRecords)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override MembershipUserCollection FindUsersByName(string usernameToMatch, int pageIndex, int pageSize, out int totalRecords)
    {
        var users = (from u in Users
                     where u.UserName.Equals(usernameToMatch, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                     select u).ToList();
        totalRecords = users.Count;
        return ToMembershipUserCollection(users);
    }

    public override MembershipUserCollection GetAllUsers(int pageIndex, int pageSize, out int totalRecords)
    {
        var list = Users.Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
        totalRecords = list.Count();
        var result = new MembershipUserCollection();
        foreach (var u in list)
        {
            result.Add(u);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public override int GetNumberOfUsersOnline()
    {
        return Users.Count();
    }

    public override string GetPassword(string username, string answer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override MembershipUser GetUser(object providerUserKey, bool userIsOnline)
    {
        return (from u in Users
                where u.ProviderUserKey.ToString() == providerUserKey.ToString()
                select u).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public override MembershipUser GetUser(string username, bool userIsOnline)
    {
        return (from u in Users
                where u.UserName.Equals(username, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                select u).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public override string GetUserNameByEmail(string email)
    {
        return (from u in Users
                where u.Email.Equals(email, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                select u.UserName).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public override int MaxInvalidPasswordAttempts
    {
        get { return 3; }
    }

    public override int MinRequiredNonAlphanumericCharacters
    {
        get { return 1; }
    }

    public override int MinRequiredPasswordLength
    {
        get { return 6; }
    }

    public override int PasswordAttemptWindow
    {
        get { return 10; }
    }

    public override MembershipPasswordFormat PasswordFormat
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public override string PasswordStrengthRegularExpression
    {
        get { return null; }
    }

    public override string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return ProviderName;
        }
    }

    public string ProviderName { get; set; }

    public override string ResetPassword(string username, string answer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool RequiresQuestionAndAnswer
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override bool RequiresUniqueEmail
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    private MembershipUserCollection ToMembershipUserCollection(IEnumerable<MembershipUser> users)
    {
        var result = new MembershipUserCollection();
        foreach (var u in users)
        {
            result.Add(u);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public override bool UnlockUser(string userName)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override void UpdateUser(MembershipUser user)
    {
        var oldUser = Users.Where(u => u.UserName.Equals(user.UserName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).Single();
        var index = Users.IndexOf(oldUser);
        Users[index] = user;
    }

    public override bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public MockMembershipProvider()
    {
        this.ProviderName = "MockMembershipProvider";
        Users = new List<MembershipUser>();
    }
}

public class FakeMembershipProvider : MockMembershipProvider
{
    public FakeMembershipProvider(string name)
    {
        this.ProviderName = name ?? "MockMembershipProvider";
    }
    public override MembershipUser CreateUser(
        string username,
        string password,
        string email,
        string passwordQuestion,
        string passwordAnswer,
        bool isApproved,
        object providerUserKey,
        out MembershipCreateStatus status)
    {
        status = MembershipCreateStatus.ProviderError;
        var user = new MockMembershipUser(); 
        user.Password = password;
        user.User = username;
        user.UserKey = providerUserKey;
        Users.Add(user);
        status = MembershipCreateStatus.Success;
        return user;
    }
}

public class MockMembershipUser : MembershipUser
{
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string User { get; set; }
    public object UserKey { get; set; }

    public override string UserName { get { return User; } }

    public override string Comment { get; set; }

    public override object ProviderUserKey { get { return UserKey; } }

    public override string GetPassword()
    {
        return Password ?? string.Empty;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to decouple your web application from `MembershipRepository`?

If so, implement all of the same functionality in a [custom MembershipProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e.aspx) so that your app will only depend on the .NET [Membership classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2d449f1x.aspx) (aside from your web.config).

If not, then don't bother.

Comment: > Do you want to decouple your web application from MembershipRepository?

No, not more than my DI already does. I just got the impression something somewhere needed a provider.

Comment: The login controls will use the default MembershipProvider by default, but you can easily override it. And if you don't want to use the Membership helper class (and similarly Roles), I don't think you will gain anything by creating a custom provider.